# GLOG multithread log

Tags: c++, logging, glog

I want to use Glog lib to log my application logs. My application is multithreaded. As Suggested in glog i have supposed to use RAW_LOG for thread safety. Here is my example code.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #define GLOG_NO_ABBREVIATED_SEVERITIES
  #include <windows.h>
  #include <glog/logging.h>
  #include <glog/raw_logging.h>
  using namespace std;

  int main(int /*argc*/, char** argv)
  {
      FLAGS_alsologtostderr = 1;

      google::SetLogDestination(google::GLOG_INFO, "E:/mylog.log");
      google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
      //LOG(INFO) << "Infomration";
      RAW_LOG_INFO("Test");

      RAW_LOG(INFO,"This is INFO");
      RAW_LOG(WARNING,"This is WARNING");
      RAW_LOG(ERROR, "This is Error");
      return 0;
   }
```

But log files are not generating if I use RAW_LOG but if I use LOG() function then log file is generating.

Please let me know how do I use RAW_LOG function or is LOG() function is threadsafe or not.

Answer (score 1):

this is from the raw_logging.h

```
// * it logs straight and ONLY to STDERR w/o buffering
```

It can only log to stderr and is only for debugging purposes in low level code 
so `RAW_LOG(INFO,"...")` will never generate any log files.